# How to reformat data in csv file with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to reformat data in csv file with this condition:

> This is the list
>
> - nothing to do for first line
> - Every line should start with double quote (") otherwise then move this line to end of previous line
> - only if the line  start with "| (double quote and pipeline as a second letter) then move this line to the end of previous line
>     For example, I have csv file which contains the following lines:

Example Case :

```
HEADER1|HEADER2
"ID001"|"AAAA"
"ID002"|"THIS LINE
MUST BE INLINE"|
"ID003"|"NEWS
- POINT 1
- POINT 2
- POINT 3
"|"TEST4"
```

Expected Result:

```
HEADER1|HEADER2
"ID001"|"AAAA"
"ID002"|"THIS LINE MUST BE INLINE"|
"ID003"|"NEWS - POINT 1 - POINT 2 - POINT 3 "|"TEST4"
```

I've already try using sed or perl but it doesn't work because of the pipeline.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please show your non-working solutions together with the (wrong) output in your question. Maybe we can help you to improve these solutions instead of inventing something new. From your output I guess that the continuation line should be separated from the previous line using a single space. Please make this clear in your question. (This should be easy to implement using `awk` or `perl`.)

Comment: why the references to CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -i -0777pe 's/\n([^"])/ $1/g' test.csv; perl -i -0777pe 's/\n("\|)/ $1/g' test.csv
```